# Mui sx styling ONLY at certain breakpoint

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, breakpoints

I am converting some old mui styling to use the `sx` attribute and have seen that you can specify styles as different breakpoints with `sx = {{ someCssProp: { xs: ..., md: ...` etc.

I have previously been using `theme.breakpoints.only` for some of my stylings and after reading the [official docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/) on breakpoint usage, it sounds like the `xs, md, ...` usage within `sx` will only apply `theme.breakpoints.up`... meaning that if I want styling only at `xs`, doing something like:

```
<Box sx={{background: {xs: 'blue'}}}>Some content</Box>
```

Will mean that the `Box` has a blue background **from** xs...

Is there a way in which I can replicate my **`.only`** use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, the [breakpoints object](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#responsive-values) syntax only applies going "up" (larger) per the docs:

> **Breakpoints as an object**
>
> The first option for breakpoints is to
> define them as an object, using the breakpoint values as keys. *Note
> that each property for a given breakpoint also applies to all larger
> breakpoints in the set. For example, `width: { lg: 100 }` is equivalent
> to `theme.breakpoints.up('lg')`*.

That does mean that with your current code the `Box` has a blue background ***from*** `xs` up.

Since you're trying to define styles for [`only`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#theme-breakpoints-only-key-media-query) one particular breakpoint, you will need to define your own behavior, using the [theme breakpoints helper functions](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries), in the `sx` prop. For example:

```
<Box
  sx={(theme) => ({
    [theme.breakpoints.only("sm")]: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }
  })}
>
  Some content
</Box>
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-breakpoints-in-sx-only-yr7h42?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Yes, this is the conclusion I had come to... Annoying, but that's how it goes.